# androidndk build error in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I am getting the following stacktrace error when I am trying to do run my android project.

> Error:java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>   Error:java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "E:\android-ndk-r14-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r14/ndk-build" (in directory "G:\downloads\WritePadSDK-master\Android\sample_astudio\app"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>   Error:net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'E:\android-ndk-r14-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r14/ndk-build'
>   Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'E:\android-ndk-r14-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r14/ndk-build''
>   Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]

Below portion is my gradle code where I am including ndk

```
 tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkLibsToJar
}


task ndkLibsToJar(type: Zip, dependsOn: 'ndkBuild', description: 'Create a JAR of the native libs') {
    destinationDir new File(buildDir, 'libs')
    baseName 'ndk-libs'
    extension 'jar'
    from(new File(buildDir, 'libs')) { include '**/*.so' }
    into 'lib/'
}

// TODO: to reduce jar size, replace APP_ABI=all with list list of CPUs you want to support

task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    def ndkDir = plugins.getPlugin('com.android.application').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder() // '/Android/android-ndk'
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build", 'APP_ABI=all', 'APP_OPTIM=release',
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk'
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Apparently it cant find a file. Do you have access to drive `G:\`

Comment: My project is lying in G drive and ndk file is in E drive...Is that a problem?

Comment: Do you have access to both files? Maybe try using a single drive instead of multiple. In Ur ndkBuild change `ndkDir/ndk-build` to `ndkBuild\ndk-build`.

Comment: I guess  I am having access to both files. Also I have defined nkDir=plugins.getPlugin('com.android.application').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder() // '/Android/android-ndk' so that I don't need to specify the file path.

Comment: Tried copying ndk file to same directory of project..But still no luck